# Replace legend squares with symbols?

Tags: flot

Is there a way to have the legend match the line points? If I change the points in my line to crosses how can I change the legend to match. The colors match but I would like to have the symbols match too, if possible.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, but this would be a great addition to the symbols plugin if you're interested in contributing.  Otherwise, you should at least file it as an enhancement in the bug tracker, if you haven't already.